# isSticky button current state Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing soft keyboard and I added a toggle button similar to the shift button to my keyboard with option isSticky=true on it. How can I control this sticky button from my code? Or actually is it even possible, since my toggle button loses state each time I change the orientation.

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
```

And I have a function with onKey to specify the key pressed.

Comment: I think that would be the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button and mine actually has a kindof virtual <kbd>CAPS</kbd> light on it. That would be "AnySoftKeyboard".

Comment: @LuxuryMode its wat owlstead said exactly .. its a small light that is usually on the shift button.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: see the following resource
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:isSticky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Handling Orientation Change: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue.  You can create a second drawable, and manually draw the sticky indicator on it.  Then load this drawable in your xml or java code - depending on your orientation.